# Select Distinct Values from different Rows

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
include("includes/dbconnect.php");
$getTagsQuery = mysql_query("
select tag, sum(tagCount as tagCount) from
(select tag1 as tag, count(*) as tagCount from videos GROUP BY tag1
UNION
select tag2 as tag, count(*) as tagCount from videos GROUP BY tag2
UNION
select tag3 as tag, count(*) as tagCount from videos GROUP BY tag3
UNION
select tag4 as tag, count(*) as tagCount from videos GROUP BY tag4
UNION
select tag5 as tag, count(*) as tagCount from videos GROUP BY tag5)
GROUP BY tag
");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getTagsQuery)){
echo "
    ".$row['tagCount']."
    ";
}
?>
```

Hello, I have this code.
What i need to do is to get the number of times that a different tag appears in the mentioned rows.
Without repeating Tags.
Why is it not working?
Can somebody help?
I am failing to get it to work.

Ty

Comment: not working **HOW**? you don't get the expected result? the code crashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want sum the numbers of all tags you should remove the last group by, to be:

```
$getTagsQuery = mysql_query("
select tag, sum(tagCount as tagCount) from
(select tag1 as tag, count(*) as tagCount from videos GROUP BY tag1
UNION
select tag2 as tag, count(*) as tagCount from videos GROUP BY tag2
UNION
select tag3 as tag, count(*) as tagCount from videos GROUP BY tag3
UNION
select tag4 as tag, count(*) as tagCount from videos GROUP BY tag4
UNION
select tag5 as tag, count(*) as tagCount from videos GROUP BY tag5)
");
```

Comment: Thank you very much @GoudaElalfy

Answer (score 0):

First of all your query looks bit weird but you might be getting an error due to the `SUM()` function `sum(tagCount as tagCount)` which should actually be

```
select tag, sum(tagCount) as tagCount from
```

Answer (score 0):

Your specific syntax problems are the typo in the outer `select` and the lack of alias on the subquery.

This is the correct query:

```
select tag, sum(tagCount) as tagCount
from ((select tag1 as tag, count(*) as tagCount from videos GROUP BY tag1
      ) UNION ALL
      (select tag2 as tag, count(*) as tagCount from videos GROUP BY tag2
      ) UNION ALL
      (select tag3 as tag, count(*) as tagCount from videos GROUP BY tag3
      ) UNION ALL
      (select tag4 as tag, count(*) as tagCount from videos GROUP BY tag4
      ) UNION ALL
      (select tag5 as tag, count(*) as tagCount from videos GROUP BY tag5
      )
     ) t
GROUP BY tag;
```

The three key changes:

- Fixing the outer `select` clause.
- Using `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.
- Adding an alias for the subquery.